# Block Connection to Specific BSSID's

Tags: android, blocking, ssid

I am setting up my friend's network for his kids. I have Tomato firmware running on their Linksys with OpenDNS filtering as well as timed Access Restrictions (ie, no more internet access after 11:30pm). That's all fine and dandy as long as my friend's son's phone stays on his network. However, he is getting access to a friend's router nearby (however, he does not have data on his phone; so I don't need to worry about that).

In Tomato, I can go to Tools > Wireless Survey and I can see all the BSSID's that are all around their house.

I also have rooted my friend's son's Android phone. Is there any way to block the phone from connecting to specific BSSID's? I have AirDroid installed and can access the root files from my house. Is there some file in there that I can edit?

Answer (score 1):

I figured things out. For one, after I added the iptable rule, I needed to REBOOT my phone for it to apply (which I wasn't doing). Secondly, I needed to use the LAN Mac Address (NOT the BSSID/Wireless MAC address) in order for the iptable rule to work.

Thirdly, I downloaded AFWall+. It allowed me to set it as administrator to prevent uninstallation. The only thing missing is that the developer needs to password protect removing the app as administrator.

Then I downloaded Android Terminal Emulator. In order to find the LAN MAC address for the connection that I am looking to block, I typed this into the emulator:

```
arp -n
```

Then I used the MAC address that was given in the terminal and put that into this rule here to be place in "custom scripts" in the firewall:

```
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source 00:00:00:00:00:00 -j DROP
```

Comment: This does not block 802.11x Association to a BSSID, it breaks TCP/IP networking to that address/gateway